# War against evil

Tags: good-and-evil

in a German television program about the NSA there was a quote saying that if people justify all means in the war against evil then their good intentions won't be distinguishable from the evil they want to destroy.

This quote was said to be from a British cultural philosopher.

Does anybody know the name of the author and the original quote?

I would appreciate your help here!

Comment: Some information why the question was voted down would be helpful for improving this or further questions!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about who-said-something rather than the idea behind the quote or something like that.

Comment: OK. Good to know. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Something like this is better suited for chat.

Comment: Thanks. I will post questions like this in the chat the next time.
Thanks for this hint!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "As soon as men decide that all means are permitted to fight an evil,
>   then their good becomes indistinguishable from the evil they set out
>   to destroy"

-- [Christopher Dawson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Dawson)

Comment: LOL "The war against evil is on hold"